# SwiftUI view identity, ForEach, structural identity and id()

Tags: swiftui, foreach, view, identity

I'm trying to decipher how identity works in SwiftUI. [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) helps, but essentially suggests there is explicit or structural identity, which is used to determine state and transitions.

Let's apply the concept on a simple test case, where I would like to shuffle two blocks back-and-forth by pressing a toggle button. The following example accomplishes this using 2 alternative methods, one with a `ForEach` and one which spells each out explicitly. Oddly enough, only the `ForEach` method appears to allow the blocks to maintain identity as they shuffle around in the container – spelling the views out with an explicit identity breaks the animation:

```swift
struct SimplePreview: PreviewProvider, View {
    static var previews = Self()

    @State
    private var isRunning = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Toggle is \(self.isRunning ? "on" : "off")") {
                withAnimation {
                    self.isRunning.toggle()
                }
            }

            // 1
            HStack {
                ForEach([self.isRunning, !self.isRunning], id: \.self) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill($0 ? Color.accentColor : Color.gray)
                }
            }
            
            // 2
            HStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(self.isRunning ? Color.blue : Color.gray)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(!self.isRunning ? Color.blue : Color.gray)
            }

            // 3
            HStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(self.isRunning ? Color.blue : Color.gray)
                    .id(self.isRunning)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(!self.isRunning ? Color.blue : Color.gray)
                    .id(!self.isRunning)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I take from this is that in case:

1. `ForEach` allows the individual items to maintain their full identity
2. The individual items have a separate structural identity and as their state changes, they transition individually.
3. The individual items have a separate structural identity, but when their internal `.id` changes, they are seen as completely new views, breaking animation entirely.

The question is then obviously:
How can maintain full view identity outside of something like `ForEach`? We want to achieve the effect seen in [1] using an approach like [2] or [3].

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this with `matchedGeometryEffect` and `@Namespace`, e.g.

```
@Namespace private var animation
```

```
          // 2
            HStack {
                if isRunning {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 1, in: animation)
                        .transition((.scale(scale: 1))) // this is to override the default transition which is opacity that looks bad.
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.gray)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 2, in: animation)
                        .transition(.scale(scale: 1))
                }
                else {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.gray)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 2, in: animation)
                        .transition(.scale(scale: 1))
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 1, in: animation)
                        .transition(.scale(scale: 1))
                }
```

[Here is a tutorial](https://medium.com/geekculture/swiftui-matchedgeometryeffect-20fa63ff9db9) covering this feature.

Here is another fun way of achieving a similar animation, the difference being the blue always slides behind the gray.

```
        // 4 
        HStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.gray)
        }
        .environment(\.layoutDirection, isRunning ? .leftToRight : .rightToLeft)
```

Comment: Thanks @malhal! You've fixed the animation, but unfortunately not the underlying identity problem. We can see this clearly if we say, also want the moving block to change color in addition to shifting. When identity is preserved, this is easy to do since we just change the fill color. But your animation paints over the original problem with a case-specific work-around that doesn't allow us to build on the solution beyond the simplified test case. Any thoughts on the underlying identity problem itself?